# Facebook Android Intent

Tags: android, facebook

i have a problem with this intent. this intent is supose to send a text type of message. everything works email,sms,twitter and whatever is on the phone. but the only one that has a problem is facebook, it will try to post as a link and not a text.

```
Intent s = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  s.setType("text/plain");
  s.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Quote");
  s.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, qoute);

  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(s, "Quote"));
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this too.  Does anyone have some sample code for how to work around the problem by sending only links to FB, but text and links to everything else?

Comment: Facebook's Eric Tseng confirmed to me on Twitter today that they're looking to fix this. Here's hoping the next release of the app correctly accepts shared text.

Comment: it's fixed in version 1.6.0 of facebook for android! yay!

Comment: It's still not working for me as of 1.9.

Comment: I tested on 2.1 version and still they didnt fix this bug :(... Any idea, whether they will work on this bug or not?

Comment: even latest 3.5 version doesn't fix this bug !!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a flaw in the Facebook application. Please complain to the authors of that application, and hopefully they will fix their bug.

Comment: I just found that even latest 3.5 version doesn't fix this bug !!!. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have decided that this is not a bug, but that's it's by design; i.e. pre-filling the Facebook app's share Intent with text is against their platform policy.

I think it was initially a bug, then they fixed it, then they removed the fix to conform to their policy.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423
- https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control ("Give people control", point 3)

The fact that they advertise their share Intent as supporting `EXTRA_TEXT` is pretty frustrating, given they they don't really support it unless the text consists of a URL.

Note that it's perfectly possible to pre-fill the text using the Facebook share controller that's built-in to iOS 6 and higher - I guess Apple play by different rules.

Madness? I agree. My solution to this problem would be to delete my Facebook account, then go have a nice cup o' tea :) Alternatively, ignore Facebook's policy, and roll your own sharing UI that talks directly to the Facebook API.