# Using built in android activity does not share to facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am using this as a guide: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

I have tested with multiple applications (Twitter,Facebook Messenger, Gmail, Hangouts, LinkedIn...) and when I choose them the text makes it into the app, however when I choose Facebook I am directed to the "Write Post" screen in Facebook but the text I sent via my activity is not there.

Am I missing something? Here is the code in question:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well [documented issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423), which Facebook have implemented by design. You cannot pre-fill a user's 'sharing text', because facebook do not want to allow this. Partly due to security. Back in '10 you could do this, so you will see old answers telling you how to do it.

These days **you can only share a link to facebook this way**.

[Here is a useful reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077289/facebook-android-intent)